# Finding and Replacing all Values inside of entries within a List

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

**Question:**
Given a list of the form:

```
[((x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), variable_1, variable_2, variable_3),
((x3,y3,z3), (x1,y1,z1), variable_4, variable_5, variable_6),...
((x1,y1,z1), (xN,yN,zN), variable_M, variable_M+1, variable_M+2)]
```

What is the most efficient (and preferably universal, ie for any list) way to replace all entries in the list matching a value (say `(x1,y1,z1)`) with another value (say `(xM,yM,zM)`)?

Central to my problem is that each entry in the list is composed of multiple elements, and typical methods I use to replace values (e.g. `[new_input if x == current else x for x in pairs]`) do not appear to be useful in this case. Note the form of *each* entry is: `((x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), variable_1, variable_2, variable_3)`, and the list is: `[((x1,y1,z1), (x2,y2,z2), variable_1, variable_2, variable_3), ((x3,y3,z3), (x1,y1,z1), variable_4, variable_5, variable_6)]`. I'm looking to change elements within the entry.

Currently I am using a reliable if crude method in which the list is broken into columns and then replaces individual elements in the list, before zipping the columns back together. The code is roughly as follows:

```
current=(x1,y1,z1)
new_input=(xM,yM,zM)
pairs=#list as above
def column(list, col_num):
    return [column[col_num] for column in list]

p_c_1=column(pairs, 0)
p_c_2=column(pairs, 1)
p_c_3=column(pairs, 2)
p_c_4=column(pairs, 3)
p_c_5=column(pairs, 4)

for i in xrange(len(pairs)):
    if p_c_1[i]==current:
       p_c_1.remove(p_c_1[i])
       p_c_1.insert(i,new_input)
    if p_c_2[i]==current:
       p_c_2.remove(p_c_2[i])
       p_c_2.insert(i,new_input)

pairs=zip(p_c_1,p_c_2,p_c_3,p_c_4,p_c_5)
```

This method yields an output:

```
[((xM,yM,zM), (x2,y2,z2), variable_1, variable_2, variable_3),
((x3,y3,z3), (xM,yM,zM), variable_4, variable_5, variable_6),...
((xM,yM,zM), (xN,yN,zN), variable_M, variable_M+1, variable_M+2)]
```

The method has proved reliable for this particular case, but as there are multiple lists with individual entries composed of several items, I have to construct a new bit of code such as that above for each unique list, which seems crude. I would ideally want to avoid disassembling and reassembling the list every time I change an entry, or automate the process at least.

What is the best way to go about this issue?

Note:
A solution would ideally be able to handle the replacement of any element within a list entry, and not just the first two columns. Other lists I have do not necessarily follow the above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `dict` that is a mapping of (things you want to replace) to (things to replace them with).

Then it's straightforward to make a new list comprehension using `dict.get` to default to the extant value if you haven't specified a replacement in your replacement-dict.

```
li = [('a','c','b'),('b','b','c'),('c','d'),'5',4]

d = {('b','b','c'):('b','b','b'),('c','d'):('c','c')}

[d.get(x,x) for x in li]
Out[33]: [('a', 'c', 'b'), ('b', 'b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), '5', 4]
```

**Edit:** since it seems you have a peculiar data structure (one giant tuple spanning the entire `list`), you can do this:

```
[tuple(d.get(x,x) for x in li[0])]
```

Or, if you actually have more of those nested outer-tuples that you're just not showing, try:

```
[tuple(d.get(x,x) for x in outer_tup) for outer_tup in li]
```

Both get you back to your original list-of-tuples-of-(tuples and other things) data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your response! :) This certainly looks like it's in the right direction of what I'm after. If my list is: `li = [(('a','c','b'),('b','b','c'),('c','d'),'5',4)]`, how then would this mapping method work? I understand that for individual entries your solution would be perfect, but if I'm looking to change an element *within* the entry, what then? Sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: @MarkyD43 So everything in your list is also in one big tuple?  Why?  I mean, yes, it's just a syntactic change on the list comp, but it would be better if you just got rid of that pointless outer-tuple.

Comment: It's written as a single big tuple because each entry contains all the info about a given data point. i.e pairs[0] returns all info relevant to the first data point. Without the second set of brackets it would be a continuous list. (Also, more importantly, it is the format in which I inherited the problem (I'm updating someone else's code) and re-writing the code would be a big task.

Comment: @MarkyD43 I see.  Were I writing that API I'd use something more self-documenting than a tuple - like a `namedtuple`!  Ah well.  My bottom edit should suffice for your needs.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I'll look into your recommendations, thank you again :)